# Drupal - Organic Groups Invite - automate process

Tags: drupal, organic-groups

Currently when one invites anynomous users to join an Organic Group on a Drupal site, the email that gets send out, only contains a link to the Organic Group. But then because the user is anonymous he will not be able to access the group unless he first registers.

So what happens presently is the user gets an emaila to join a group, clicks on the link, but then gets the access denied page.

Is there a way to automate the process, so that the user gets directed to the registration page, and after registering gets redirrected to the group that he was invited too. Either to then  automtically become a member, as he was already invited or to then manually join.

thanks
Charles

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that, but it will be hard to make something that wont be fragile.

You can take a look at the [Redirect 403 to User Login](http://drupal.org/project/r4032login) module. It redirects anonymous users to the login page. You can either use that as a basis to build your own module, I would imagine only a few tweaks would be needed to make it work how you want.

You might be able to alter the module with your own module, to make it function like you want, but I don't know exactly how it's built and if that's an option.